# Going to a function of controller with javascript in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a button in my view page.I want to go to a function of controller by clicking on the button.How can I do this with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function btnclick(){
window.location.href = "<?php echo(site_url("controller_name/function_name")); ?>";
}
</script>
<button value="Button Name" onclick="btnclick();" />
```

You must enable url helper in autoload config to use site_url() function

Comment: I write that code but when I click on button it does not work.I see the console  it shows an error which say:back is undefined.`back` is the name of my function.

Comment: @setara instead of site_url() use base_url()

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function redirect()
{                       
     var base_url= "<?php echo site_url('controller_name/function');?>";
     window.location.href = base_url;
}   

</script> 

<input type="button" value="button" onclick="redirect();" />
```